# Return a count of the number of strings in the array that can be successfully converted into a number

Tags: javascript

So I am writing a little function that will return a count of the number of strings in the array that can be successfully converted into a number.

In other words, the string "1" can be successfully converted to the number 1, but the string "hello" cannot be converted into a number.

Here is what I have so far:

```js
function countNumbers(arr) {
  var conversion = Number(arr);
  return conversion;
}

console.log(
countNumbers(['a','b','3','awesome','4']), // 2
countNumbers(['32', '55', 'awesome', 'test', '100']), // 3
countNumbers([]), // 0
countNumbers(['4','1','0','NaN']), // 3
countNumbers(['7', '12', 'a', '', '6', '8', ' ']) // 4
  );
```

Would the `Number()` function be best suited for this task? Or `parseInt()`? Currently it is only returning: `NaN NaN 0 NaN NaN`, when it should be returning `2 3 0 3 4`.

Comment: Trying to convert an array to a number will always return `NaN`. Try looping over the array with `forEach` or `filter`.

Comment: You haven't written any logic for counting anything. `Number(arr)` tries to convert *the entire array* to a single number, it does not iterate over the array and return the number of successful conversions. Use a loop with a counter.

Comment: What should the result be for `"123banana"`? Would it be counted or not?

Comment: Also, what about `"3.14"`? Are you counting non-integers?

Answer (score 0):

Use `Number()` and `isNaN` like this:

```js
function countNumbers(arr) {
  arr = arr.filter(x => x.trim().length !== 0).map(x => x.trim())
  const total = arr.reduce((acc, x) => !isNaN(Number(x)) ? acc + 1 : acc, 0)
  return total;
}

console.log(
countNumbers(['a','b','3','123banana','4']), // 2
countNumbers(['32', '55', 'awesome', 'test', '100']), // 3
countNumbers([]), // 0
countNumbers(['4','1','0','NaN']), // 3
countNumbers(['7', '12', 'a', '', '6', '8', ' ']) // 4
  );
```

Comment: `parseInt` does not necessarily return the correct result. It depends on what you consider correct, at least: `"123banana"` will not be a numer according to `Number` while `parseInt` will successfully parse it. Whether or not you consider `"123banana"` a number should be an important consideration.

Comment: thanks @VLAZ, I edited the code snippet, now it works right

Answer (score 0):

Your current implementation makes no attempt to actually *count* anything, it just hopes `Number()` will do the exact behavior you want (it doesn't).

Something like this would be fine:

```js
function countNumbers(arr) {
  return arr.filter(n => !isNaN(n) && !isNaN(parseInt(n))).length;
}

console.log(
countNumbers(['a','b','3','awesome','4']), // 2
countNumbers(['32', '55', 'awesome', 'test', '100']), // 3
countNumbers([]), // 0
countNumbers(['4','1','0','NaN']), // 3
countNumbers(['7', '12', 'a', '', '6', '8', ' ']), // 4
countNumbers(['123banana','3','','   ',' ','6','3numbers','5']), //3
 );
```

*Thanks to @PrashantSharma for the more concise implementation*

I use `!isNaN(n) && !isNaN(parseInt(n))` because the first one checks that the string is **only** a number (parseInt thinks `12px` is a number for example) and the second discards empty spaces (`''` isn't a number but it passes the first check because... javascript)

Comment: Lil bit optimization
`function countNumbers(arr) {
  return arr.filter(n => !isNaN(n) && !isNaN(parseInt(n))).length;
}`

Comment: @PrashantSharma That's excellent, very efficient and concise. Thanks.